# Reading Little Endian unsigned long in Java

Tags: java, endianness

I'm new to Java (I'm coming from C/C++) and I need to read an unsigned 4 byte number stored in LittleEndian.

My function doesn't work (I've just finished searching on internet, and it seems correct...)

```
public long readlU32() throws IOException {
                long dword = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                        dword = (dword << 8) | readU8();
                return dword;
        }
```

I saw other questions here and it should work... What's wrong?

P.S.: The value I have to read is 0x94010000, so the value should be 404, but the program read it as 2483093504 (Big Endian value)...

Comment: Longs in java are 8 bytes. Did you try with 8 instead of 4?

Comment: You are shifting the first byte you read the most to the left. That would make the first byte the biggest, so yes, you implemented big endian reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are shifting bytes in so that the "left most" byte winds up being the "left most" still.  You are converting the bit representation of `404` as little endian, `0x94010000` into what it would represent in big-endian, which is `2483093504`.

Try this, which will shift each byte read into the `long` bytes starting from the end.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    dword = dword | (readU8() << (8 * i));
}
```